# How to update/reload LogLevels, configured by appsettings.json at runtime?

Tags: c#, logging, .net-6.0, appsettings, kestrel

I am working on a **.NET6 Kestrel** application using **appsettings.json** for configuration and **default console logging**.

What I try to do is, that I want to change log-levels at runtime. However, so far the log-levels were only updated on restart.

Am I missing something besides *reloadOnChange=true*?

Here's the relevant code:
[image: Code]

```
static void Configure(IConfigurationBuilder config)
{
  config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false, true);
  config.AddEnvironmentVariables();
}
ConfigurationBuilder cb = new();
Configure(cb);
IConfigurationRoot configuration = cb.Build();
IWebHostBuilder webHost = WebHost
  .CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
  .ConfigureLogging(c =>
  {
    c.AddConfiguration(configuration);
    c.AddConsole();
  })
  .ConfigureAppConfiguration(Configure)
  .UseStartup<TStartup>();
```

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: Sorry for that! Added the code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to manually add these files because [`CreateDefaultBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.webhost.createdefaultbuilder#microsoft-aspnetcore-webhost-createdefaultbuilder) already takes care of that for you.

Additionally, when you run the app in Visual Studio, it automatically sets the "Development" environment variable (as specified in [launchSettings.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments#development-and-launchsettingsjson)). Consequently, the `appsettings.development.json` file will take precedence. Therefore, ensure that you are making changes in the correct file corresponding to the current environment.

---

I've made a simple POC and it just works fine here, please give a try:

Program.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

IWebHostBuilder webHost = WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).UseStartup<Startup>();

webHost.Build().Run();

public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => { endpoints.MapControllers(); });
    }
}

[Route("test")]
[ApiController]
public class TestController
{
    private readonly ILogger<TestController> _logger;

    public TestController(ILogger<TestController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        _logger.LogTrace("Trace log!");
        _logger.LogDebug("Debug log!");
        _logger.LogInformation("Information log!");
        _logger.LogWarning("Warning log!");
        _logger.LogError("Error log!");
        _logger.LogCritical("Critical log!");

        return new OkResult();
    }
}
```

Changes on `appsettings.json` file immediately takes effect on logger output to console when calling the test endpoint.

[image: SettingsUpdateTest]

Comment: Thank you for the comment!
I removed the additional files from the example. I have some more files in there.
When restarting the changes I made do take effect, therefore I am sure that I am modifying the corret files.

Comment: I've updated the answer with my test

Comment: Thank you so much!
I am running the application in docker, since I want to test locally as close to prod as possible. It does indeed work, when running it directly in VS!!!
I am not quite sure why it does not work when running in docker. I can see the changes in the appsettings.json when exec terminal in the container and cat the content.
Maybe the underlying filewatcher does not recognize the changes?
Gonna look into it. Knowing that it generally works on our side is worth so much and I am dump for not checking that earlier.
Thanks a ton again!!!

Comment: Do you happen to know a way to force refresh the config or how to configure this to work in a docker container?
I touched the file and made sure that the last modified timestamp does in fact change. But it just does not reload the configuration :(

Comment: I don't know for sure if the behavior is different on docker, but I'll also take a look here

Comment: Thank you for your effort! Eventually I figured it out!
Seems like in docker the filewatcher does indeed have problems. But there already is a solution for this (see [.NET Core Watch Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/dotnet-watch?view=aspnetcore-7.0#dotnet-watch-configuration)).
With the env `DOTNET_USE_POLLING_FILE_WATCHER=true` it finally works.

Comment: Very nice! Thanks for sharing!